# Custom action button in WooCommerce admin orders that send an email

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I added a action button in the order page, the problem is no passing any data to the function.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'add_customer_second_payment_reminder_button', 100, 2 );
function add_customer_second_payment_reminder_button( $actions, $order ) {
    if ( $order->has_status(array( 'partially-paid' ) )) {
        $actions['email_reminder'] = array(
            'url'       => wp_nonce_url( admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=customer_second_payment_reminder_button&order_id=' . $order->get_id() )),
            'name'      => __( 'Email Second Payment Reminder' , 'woocommerce-deposits' ),
            'action'    => 'email_reminder',
        );
    }
    return $actions;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_customer_second_payment_reminder_button', 'customer_second_payment_reminder_button' );
function customer_second_payment_reminder_button( $order_id ) {
  do_action( 'woocommerce_deposits_second_payment_reminder_email' , $order_id );
}

add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_customer_second_payment_reminder_button_css' );
function add_customer_second_payment_reminder_button_css() {
    echo '<style>.wc-action-button-'.'email_reminder'.'::after { font-family: woocommerce !important; content: "\e030" !important; }</style>';
}
```

so always show a 0 when i use the button.
customer_second_payment_reminder_button function don't receive the ?order_id parameter from the url.
i put a var_dump($order_id); in the function and show string(0) "" 0

how i can pass the order id to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes and some missing things in your code:

- There are no function arguments with `wp_ajax_{action}` or `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}` action hooks.
- The order ID is sent via the URL, so you can catch it through `$_GET` variable
- You have to secure your Ajax function and to embed a redirection at the end. If not you get a white page. Also never forget `exit;` at the end...

So your functional code will be:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'add_customer_second_payment_reminder_button', 100, 2 );
function add_customer_second_payment_reminder_button( $actions, $order ) {
    if ( $order->has_status( array('partially-paid') ) ) {
        $actions['email_reminder'] = array(
            'url'    => wp_nonce_url(
                admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=customer_second_payment_reminder&order_id=' . $order->get_id() ),
                'customer-second-payment-reminder'
            ),
            'name'   => __( 'Email Second Payment Reminder', 'woocommerce-deposits' ),
            'action' => 'email_reminder',
        );
    }
    return $actions;
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_customer_second_payment_reminder', 'get_customer_second_payment_reminder' );
function get_customer_second_payment_reminder() {
    if ( current_user_can('edit_shop_orders') && check_admin_referer('customer-second-payment-reminder') &&
    isset($_GET['order_id']) && get_post_type( absint( wp_unslash($_GET['order_id']) ) ) === 'shop_order' ) {
        $order_id = absint( wp_unslash($_GET['order_id']) );
        $order    = wc_get_order($order_id);

        if( is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
            do_action( 'woocommerce_deposits_second_payment_reminder_email', $order_id, $order );
            update_post_meta( $order_id, '_reminder_button', 'OK' ); // For testing purpose (to be removed)
        }
    }
    wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=shop_order' ) );
    exit;
}

add_action( 'admin_head', 'customer_second_payment_reminder_button_css' );
function customer_second_payment_reminder_button_css() {
    global $pagenow;

    if( $pagenow === 'edit.php' && isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] === 'shop_order' ) {
        echo '<style>.wc-action-button-'.'email_reminder'.'::after { font-family: woocommerce !important; content: "\e02d" !important; }</style>';
    }
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks, that work perfectly, and now i understand. I was almost sure that wp_ajax funtion can have arguments. i see that you put 2 check, that is a really nice touch